# A question of countable product and uncountable product

Tags: separable-spaces

It is intuitive and easy to show that a countable product of separable spaces is separable. It is tempting to think that an uncountable product of separable spaces will not be separable
(a) Show that R^R is separable. Can the same be said about (R^R,Tbox)?
Hint: Consider the collection of all step functions with finitely many steps, rational
step heights, and whose steps are all on rational intervals.
(b) This might help you partially regain your sanity. Show that there exists a subspace
of R^R that is not separable.
Hint: Forf∈RR,definethesetA:={g∈R^R |g(x)=f(x)for all but countably
many x ∈ R}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).